# maximums of vector

Tags: matlab

If I have `a=[2 5 7 1 7]` then is there a way that MATLAB returns the indices of both 7s in the vector? I mean I am looking for a command that returns `max=7` and `idx=[3 5]`.

Comment: Just a word of caution if you end up trying this with floating point values rather than integers: some values may look similar when displayed at the command prompt, but actually have small differences. As a result `a==m` may miss some values that you think are also maxes.

Answer (score 5):

Use `max` and then `find`:

```
m = max(a):
idx = find(a==m);
```